# Go_Router redirects me to '/register' page everytime i try to navigate routes using context.push('/anylocation') in my UI (redirect gets triggered)

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

so basically i dont see what i am doing wrong. everything makes sense to me, must be some minor thing that is escaping me. but basically i created my routes and in there i have a redirect property which is conditional of the authentification state. the riderection works just fine, the problem is that it gets triggered everytime i try to push other routes and i end up always in the '/register' page.

i have added a print(state.location) in the redirect property to see what is happening and when im in my register page and i try to navigate to the login page by pressing a button the print statement prints in the terminal twice, first it prints '/login' and then it prints '/register'

my code is as follows:

```
class AppRouter {
  final AuthBloc authBloc;
  late final GoRouter routes;
  AppRouter({required this.authBloc}) {
    routes = GoRouter(
      initialLocation: '/register',
      refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(authBloc.stream),
      redirect: (context, state) {
        print(state.location);
        if (authBloc.state is AuthUnauthenticatedState) {
          if (state.location != '/register') {
            return '/register';
          }
        } else if (authBloc.state is AuthAuthenticatedState) {
          return '/app';
        }
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/home',
          builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/login',
          builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/register',
          builder: (context, state) => const RegisterPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/app',
          builder: (context, state) => const AppPage(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class GoRouterRefreshStream extends ChangeNotifier {
  GoRouterRefreshStream(Stream<dynamic> stream) {
    notifyListeners();
    _subscription = stream.asBroadcastStream().listen(
          (dynamic _) => notifyListeners(),
        );
  }

  late final StreamSubscription<dynamic> _subscription;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```